# stdout silent failure

Tags: c++, stdout, iostream

I'm trying to output a zlib compressed string to stdout and something really strange happens. After running the zlib deflate operation successfully (all the correct return values checked), I try to output the result unformatted with either of these methods:

```
fwrite((void*)output, 1, numbytes, stdout);
```

OR

```
for(int i=0; i != numbytes; ++i)
    cout.put(output[c]);
if(!cout.good())
    throw error();
```

In either case nothing is output and stdout is broken. In the case of the iostream code, cout.good() returns true, no failbits are set! When using fwrite I check ferror and thats fine too!!! By stdout being broken, I mean that nothing is output via stdout for the rest of the app session. I tried reseting the stdout error state with the respective interfaces to no avail.

I'm strongly inclined to believe this is a library error, as something like this really shouldn't malfunction silently.

All this is happening under OSX 10.6 running XCode 4.2.

Comment: Have you tried flushing before checking for errors?  `fflush(stdout)`, or `cout.flush()`

Comment: Have you checked the return of fwrite to see how many bytes were written?  I don't think that's the problem because of stdout not outputting for the rest of the app, but worth a check.

Comment: In your C++ code, you're calling output[c], but c isn't defined in the code. Is that supposed to be output[i]?

Comment: Sorry, this is an XCode or GDB error, I can't reproduce from console or on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an XCode or GDB issue. I can't reproduce the error running from console, or under Windows.